# Hashing using md5 and sign using private certificate

Tags: java, cryptography, md5, string-hashing, pkcs#1

I have a requirement wherein I have to generate a URL where one of the parameter is signature and signature has to be generated using below requirement in a Java Application:

The other 4 URL parameter values should be hashed (in the order specified below) using MD5 and sign using the private certificate. (The signature will be DER-encoded PKCS #1 block as defined in RSA Laboratory's Public Key Cryptography Standards Note #1.) The resulting digest should be converted to ASCII character set using base64 and then encoded to comply with HTTP URL character set limitations.

```
Order                   Parameter
1                       [queryparameter1]
2..                     [queryparameter …] *
3                       Expiration
```

The final url should look something like

```
https://<ServerName>:<Port>/imageRet/pod?ID=123456789&build=XHB&date=201102151326&expiration=20110218155523&signature=H767dhghjKJ#23mxi
```

I have never worked on Cryptography before and hence don't know how to start.
Can somebody help how can this be achived.

Comment: The bit about "I have never worked on Cryptography before" is a little like a podiatrist saying "I have never never worked on heart surgery before" but I'll just ask in SurgeryOverflow, how hard can it be to get it right. IOW, get a cryptographic domain expert.

Comment: @zaph What is wrong in learning something new. I don't have Cryptography expert, that's why I am asking the experts here.

Comment: Good point if learning is what it is about and there are many books and much information available. But if you are just interested in a quick fix there is a problem, it is very easy even for those experienced in crypto to make a mistake. A crypto mistake is not just a bug that something does not work correctly or a crash where a re-boot is all that is necessary, a successful attack is permanent and puts all of the users at risk. Users trust the developers and that trust is the developer's responsibility.

Comment: "I don't have Cryptography expert", there are cryptographic experts who have years of experience behind them for hire, I have hired them to vett my work. Yes, they cost money just like you and I do.

Comment: MD5 should not be used for signatures anymore. Your URL definitely allows to much variance for MD5 to be an option; there seem to be few mitigating circumstances; the only issue may be the character encoding required for the parameters. 1. learn crypto 2. implement crypto; in that order.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the signature code

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(canonicalize(params));
byte signature[] = sig.sign();
String signatureB64UrlEncoded = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
```

Where `canonicalize(params)` means converting the `String`  parameters of the url to `byte[]` the way your service specified. You have not given details. This step is not trivial at all because equivalent urls may generate different signatures.

For example

```
 q=hello%20world   --> Qazz_tVB-guYai5oW0Eef6BbVP ...
 q=hello world     --> JJWDEPMQDmffcsjR0dP3vnrkFT ...
```

An example implementation, but surely not valid...

```
//Convert params[] to byte[] converting each String to byte with default charset and concatenating results
public byte[] canonicalize(String params[] ) throws IOException{
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    for (String param: params){
        out.write(param.getBytes());
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Take a look at [Amazon AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html) to see an example of how canonicalize a URL

If you finally decide to use a more secure algorithm, simply replace `MD5withRSA` with for example `SHA256withRSA`